# asp.net mvc remote validation in a Kendo window in IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, jquery-validate

I have a Kendo Window in which the user enters a Name. I'm using Remote Validation to check if the name exists in the database and submit the form only if the Name does not exist.

I'm using jQuery Validation Plugin v1.10.0. The same remote validation action is used in a normal view without any problem. But, in the Kendo Window (Partial View), I have these issues:

1) Remote validation does not fire on form submit. It only works on key up event, and on focus out. This happens both in IE (IE 8) and in Chrome.

2) In IE (IE 8), the validation only fires on key up, and only when I hit a space after the name. So, let's say the name 'John' is not valid. I will not get the validation message when I type 'John', but when I hit space after 'John'. Also, remote validation does not fire when I use backspace.

Any idea as to what is causing this issue?

**ViewModel:**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Remote("IsNameAvailable", "MyController", ErrorMessage = "The Name already exists.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult IsNameAvailable(Portfolio portfolio)
{
    var exists = // code to check if Name exists;

    return Json(!exists, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public ActionResult ShowDialog(int id)
{
    var viewModel = new MyViewModel { ID = id };

    return PartialView("_Dialog", viewModel);                    
}
```

**Partial View (to be rendered in a Kendo Window):**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)            
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)        
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
}
```

**Main View:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window().Name("dialog")
    .Title("Dialog")
    .Visible(false)
    .Modal(true)
    .Draggable(true)
    .Width(300)
    .Events(events => events.Refresh("onRefresh"))
)

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showDialog(id) {
        var wnd = $("#dialog").data("kendoWindow");
        var url = '@Url.Action("ShowDialog", "MyController")'; 

        wnd.refresh(
        {
            url: url,
            data: { id: id}
        });

        wnd.center().open();
    }

    function onRefresh(e) {
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("#dialog"));
        $.validator.setDefaults({
            onkeyup: true,
            onfocusout: true,
            onsubmit: true
        });

        var form = $("#dialog").find('form');
        form.submit(function () {
            if (form.validate().valid()) {
                var wnd = $("#dialog").data("kendoWindow");
                wnd.close();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is breaking the plugin...

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    onkeyup: true,
    onfocusout: true,
    onsubmit: true
});
```

`true` is not a valid value for the `onkeyup`, `onfocusout`, and `onsubmit` options.  These can only be set to `false` to disable or a function to over-ride.  If you want these options activated, you simply need to leave them out... those are already the defaults.

[See documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)...

> **onkeyup**
>  Type: Boolean or Function()
>  Validate elements on keyup. As long as the field is not marked as invalid, nothing happens.
>   Otherwise, all rules are checked on each key up event. Set to `false` to
>   disable. Set to a Function to decide for yourself when to run
>   validation.  **A boolean `true` is not a valid value.**
>
> **onfocusout**
>  Type: Boolean or Function()
>  Validate elements (except checkboxes/radio buttons) on blur. If nothing is entered, all
>   rules are skipped, except when the field was already marked as
>   invalid. Set to a Function to decide for yourself when to run
>   validation. **A boolean `true` is not a valid value.**
>
> **onsubmit** (default: true)
>  Type: Boolean
>  Validate the form on submit. Set to `false` to use only other events for validation. Set
>   to a Function to decide for yourself when to run validation. **A
>   boolean `true` is not a valid value.**

Comment: Thanks for the information! But, this, obviously, does not solve my problem. I had tried it before without setting the defaults.

Comment: @ataravati, however, once you fix the current issue, these improper settings ***will*** break the plugin.

Comment: I've already removed them. Thanks! I think I know what my issue is. It must have to do with the remote validation being asynchronous. At least, that's why the validation does not work when I submit the form.